# Twilio TaskRouter - Whisper and recording

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have two questions regarding TaskRouter.

1. How do I record a call when using TaskRouter?
2. How do I whisper to the worker when a call is bridged with caller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

1. When you receive an assignment callback and you connect the caller with an agent using the `call` or `dequeue` instruction, you can send back further attributes in the response. To record the call, send the attribute `record` with the value `record-from-answer` to record the entire call.
2. To whisper to a worker you need to use the `call` instruction in your assignment callback. You can then supply a URL that will get called when the agent picks up the call before bridging the calls together which you can use as a whisper.

So, for example:

```
<?php
$reservationSid = $_REQUEST['ReservationSid'];    

header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Say>You have a new call!</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Queue reservationSid="<?php echo $reservationSid ?>"></Queue>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

See the documentation for [initiating a call in the assignment callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/handling-assignment-callbacks#initiating-call) for more information.

Comment: 1. If the call is in queue and there are no agents available. What will happen? How do I forward to voicemail?   2. Do TaskRouter take care of distributing calls evenly among the agents?

Comment: 1. You can handle this yourself. For sending to voicemail I recommend a timeout on your main queue that then sends the call to a queue that is attended by one worker that immediately redirects any assignment instructions to TwiML that uses `<Record>` to take voicemail.
2. Yes it does.

Comment: What is the url called when timeout occurs?

Comment: When the timeout occurs the task is routed into a new queue, you can get an event callback ([check the docs for event callbacks here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/events)), but the task will also be moved into a new queue, if your workflow is setup that way. Then in the new queue, if there are workers (like I suggest a dummy worker for voicemail) one of them will be picked and a new assignment callback will fire too.